# ISet not being serialized C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a class, which at the top of it I have set the flag [Audit], and this then allows the contents of the object to be written out to a text for auditing purposes. However, one of the properties to this class is an ISet Some class, and the contents of this object is not being written out. It doesn't throw an error.

The [Audit] is set step up as follows, and I just wondering whether something else needs to be tweaked here, or can't ISet contents be written out:

```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true]
   public sealed class Audit:Attribute
   {}
```

Attribute is the class in System Namespace.

Comment: The code you pasted isn't pertinent.  Show us the code that actually does the auditing.

Comment: You have the attributes at the top of the class. That is all it takes

Comment: They want to see the serialisation code

Comment: I am voting to close.  The question needs to contain the code responsible for exhibiting the problem.  The declaration of an attribute has nothing to do with how `ISet` is or isn't being audited.

Comment: That is it. You need to look at attributes at the top

Comment: How are the contents of the object written. An attribute doesn't magically serialize a class, there needs to be some code that does this. And for what it's worth, using JSON.NET I successfully deserialized an ISet<int> into its appropriate JSON, so you're doing something incorrect.

Comment: @Andy5 How can we tell what the attribute is supposed to be doing? You haven't given us any code that helps answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with serialisation and `ISet`

if you look at the code for [`CollectionDataContractCriticalHelper`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/CollectionDataContract.cs,1e10273509c6e188,references) () you will see the following

```
internal static Type[] KnownInterfaces
        {
            get
            {
                if (_knownInterfaces == null)
                {
                    // Listed in priority order
                    _knownInterfaces = new Type[]
                {
                    Globals.TypeOfIDictionaryGeneric,
                    Globals.TypeOfIDictionary,
                    Globals.TypeOfIListGeneric,
                    Globals.TypeOfICollectionGeneric,
                    Globals.TypeOfIList,
                    Globals.TypeOfIEnumerableGeneric,
                    Globals.TypeOfICollection,
                    Globals.TypeOfIEnumerable
                };
                }
                return _knownInterfaces;
            }
        }
```

You will see the `ISet` is missing. Microsoft are aware of the issue but are not planning on fixing it in the near future:

[DataContractSerializer cannot serialize System.Collections.Generic.ISet even if it derives from IEnumerable](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/797718/datacontractserializer-cannot-serialize-system-collections-generic-iset-t-even-if-it-derives-from-ienumerable)

Comment: Thanks David.  Obviously you understand what I am trying to do